# Sharepoint 2010 Table of contents not showing pages

Tags: sharepoint

I'm trying to display a vertical hierarchy of sites/pages on a publishing site so I've been looking at the table of contents web part which looks like it will do what I want but for some reason it only displays subsites and not pages.

I've changed the site settings to display pages and selected the show pages option on the webpart but still it doesn't show the pages.  I'm logged in as admin so permissions aren't an issue.

Anyone got any suggestions!?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Did you enable the 'Show content from starting location' option in the webpart settings ?

Comment: Yep added that already, I'm sure it must be something simple but I can't find it!

Comment: Are your pages checked in ? Did you select enough levels to display in de the webpart properties ?

Comment: Ah yes Tom you are a star!!  Pages weren't checked in, I knew it had to be something stupid I was doing!

Comment: Now it's working but the next problem is that it doesn't display folders within the pages, do you know if this is possible at all?  Or do I need to look at a custom webpart etc?

Comment: I don't think the OOB table of contents webpart can handle folders, you'll have to develop something to get that working.